# Location of secret_id_key when built from sources

Tags: private-key

I ran tor on my raspian machine from the repositories. Since this version is quite old I built a newer version from sources. The files like config, etc., are located under /usr/local -- where the repository-installation put them directly in /etc/.
I want to copy my old secret_id_key that I obtained from /var/lib/tor/keys to the new built. However, I cannot find a specific location (/usr/local/lib does not yield a tor directory).
Any ideas (or solutions) where to put this file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PREFIX/data/keys, where prefix is `--prefix=xxx` and in my case - I've made a double-precaution :

- `configure --prefix=/usr/tor`
- in **torrc** `DataDirectory /usr/tor/data`

and NO problem is given at all, I have ALL the keys in */usr/tor/data/keys*

Comment: Do you mean with PREFIX `/usr/local`? The key fodlers are not there. Could you please specify your answer?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT if you haven't changed the prefix in configure and in `torrc` - yes, it should be there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The `torrc` states that the default is $HOME/.tor where the files are. The option `DataDirectory /usr/local/var/lib/tor` to specify the folder to `/usr/local` is commented out.